# Eclipse stops highlighting references after a while

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

When I open a Java file for editing in Eclipse, references highlighting works well for a while, but then suddenly stops working after some minutes.

On this example, `parameters` was the last variable correctly highlighted, but now it's no longer working and not highlighting anything else (it should highlight `password`):

[image: Screenshot of problem example]

Toggling `Mark Occurrences` off and back on doesn't solve it. I've already tried restarting Eclipse and rebooting the computer (had this problem for weeks actually).

The only workaround I found so far is closing the file, and reopening it. But then it stops working again after some time.

For info, I am using Eclipse 4.2.2, on Windows 7 64 bit machine.

Comment: Is this problem project dependent? Have you tried with new project? Does occurrence highlight works there?

Comment: @aardvark It's the same in all my projects.

Comment: Occurrence checking may fail on syntax or dependency error also. Have you tried this with fresh eclipse 4.2 installation?

Comment: @aardvark I've installed Eclipse Juno (can't remember which version exactly) and did the updates via `Help > Check for Updates`. I'll do a fresh install if I can't do otherwise.

Comment: There is possibility with properties of project are mangled. I had this on Linux and fixed with fresh install and deleting workspace metadata. Not really sure if this is your situation. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

WORKAROUND: select something in the Outline view (on the right) and then go back to the editor.

(For more info see [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398509))

Comment: Thanks.That works for a while, but not for too long. It was getting locked up again. For me the issue was that i was running eclipse for few days continously without closing it. I use to hibernate the system with eclipse kept open. once i closed and opened , the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

It's already reported as Eclipse Juno [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402526) and the reason is in [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398509). Looks like [this](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/commit/?id=2223c41bef449202fb6017ee8d7a571cf3e5010f) update should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that pointer. It also explains why the Git staging view doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Known bug in Juno,this feature goes Off/On frequently. I'm using  **Alt+Shift+O** as workaround!!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install the next (currently development) version - Eclipse Kepler (4.3) M7 - from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php. The highlighting issue is fixed there.

But beware it is not release version so something might not be finished yet.