# eclipse stopped highlighting references to variable

Tags: java, eclipse

[This question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876890/eclipse-stops-highlighting-references-after-a-while) but it was 2 years ago and I'm using a new version of eclipse.

The issue is in eclipse 4.4.1 Luna.  When I place the cursor over a variable, it no longer highlights the references to that variable.  The solutions suggested in the above post don't seem to do the trick.  Even closing the project and rebooting eclipse doesn't solve it.

The related bug says that the issue was solved, so I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this issue in a later version of eclipse, and if so if they have a way to fix it.

Comment: Make sure the 'Toggle Mark Occurrences' button is pressed on the tool bar.

Comment: I have this issue sometimes, too. Simply disabling 'Toggle Mark Occurrences' and enabling it again usually helps.

Comment: Tried that. It didn't help